# when will wso2 support bpmn 2.0

Tags: wso2, bpel, bpmn

I am just wondering when is WSO2 planning on supporting BPMN 2.0 in the process engine?

I would expect this to be a priority because its a better standards base than BPEL on which to build business processes.

Would this be either a replacement/alternative for or alongside the BPEL process engine ?

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Support for BPMN 2.0 is already in the roadmap. 
BPEL and BPMN, both for describing and executing business processes, you have the freedom of choosing which notation is to use.
BPEL is well suited to model some kinds of processes and BPMN is well suited to model other kinds of processes, or sometimes you can mix and match within a single composite.

WSO2 BPS executes business processes written using WS-BPEL 2.0, BPEL4WS 1.1 and also it has support for workflows with human interaction (WS-Human Task 1.1, BPEL4People 1.1).

For more information http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/BPS+Features

Thanks

Thilini

Answer (score 0):

I come across a documentation about the future release of WSO2 Business Process Server **3.5.0** which is the successor of the current released version(3.2.0).

It says that the BPMN support comes with 3.5.0: https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/About+this+Release

It seems that they integrated **activiti** business process engine with WSO2 BPS: https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/Managing+BPMN